# Phonegap and LocalStorage issue but working in browser

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-build

I must use localstorage in my phonegap (3.0) app so that I can call the specific number want by the user in each page. In order to do that I use a form and a script like that below. This script work in browser but not with phonegap build. I should have miss something but can't find what!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <title>local storage</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b3/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b3/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <style>
        #message {
            display: none;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #ff0000;
            color: #fff;
        }

        #storageDemoPage h2 {
            white-space: normal;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var localStorageKey = "allo";
        $('#storageDemoPage').live('pagecreate', function() {
                showStoreValue();
            $('#addToStorage').click(function(e) {
                localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, $('#entry').val());
                showStoreValue();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });

        function showStoreValue() {
            var item = localStorage.getItem(localStorageKey);
            if (item == null) {
                item = 'Pas de valeur';
            }
            else if (item.length === 0) {
                item = 'Aucune valeur d\'enregistrée';
            }
            $('.storeItem').text(item);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<section data-role="page" id="storageDemoPage">
    <section data-role="header">
        <h2>My app</h2>
    </section>
    <section data-role="content">
        <p id="message"/>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Enter your number</li>
            <li>
                <input type="text" id="entry" name="entry" placeholder="Write digits"/>
                <input type="button" id="addToStorage" value="Store value"/>
            </li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">Value record</li>
            <li class="storeItem"/>
        </ul>
          <div data-role="content">
            <p id="audio_position"></p>
            <ul id="allRepos" data-role="listview"></ul>
          </div>
    </section>    
</body>
</html>
```

Edit : add cordova script at the begining

Comment: in phonegap try to listen deviceready instead of pagecreate before you access the localstorage.

Comment: This doesn't work is that you have in mind?    
        
        var localStorageKey = "allo";
        
        document.addEventListener("showStoreValue", onDeviceReady, false);
        
        $('#storageDemoPage').live('onDeviceReady', function() {
                showStoreValue();
            $('#addToStorage').click(function(e) {
                localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, $('#entry').val());
                showStoreValue();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @QuickFix and @Chris here is the solution :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    var localStorageKey = "allo";

    function onDeviceReady() {
        showStoreValue();
            $('#addToStorage').click(function(e) {
                window.localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, $('#entry').val());
                showStoreValue();
                e.preventDefault();
            });

    }

        function showStoreValue() {
            var item = localStorage.getItem(localStorageKey);
            if (item == null) {
                item = 'Pas de valeur';
            }
            else if (item.length === 0) {
                item = 'Aucune valeur d\'enregistrée';
            }
            $('.storeItem').text(item);
        }    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the possible things you would have missed

a)Cordova script file inclusion in your head tag.

b)Use and listen device ready before using local storage.

Implementing this should solve your issue.

Comment: Hi Chris, Sure I had the cordova script in my dev app, you're right I should have include here (i'll update the question). I will try the b solution, thanks for your help